# Como faço pra exibir uma mensagem abaixo do meu formulário sem redirecionamento? OBS não uso banco de dados

Tags: javascript, html, css, formulário

```js
<?php
if(isset( $_POST['Nome']))      // Vai adicionar o elemento
$name = $_POST['Nome'];         // Vai enviar o elemento
if(isset( $_POST['E-mail']))     // Vai adicionar o elemento
$email = $_POST['E-mail'];       // Vai enviar o elemento
if(isset( $_POST['Telefone']))      // Vai adicionar o elemento
$fone = $_POST['Telefone'];         // Vai enviar o elemento
if(isset( $_POST['Mensagem']))   // Vai adicionar o elemento
$message = $_POST['Mensagem'];   // Vai enviar o elemento

$content="From: $name \n E-mail: $email \n Telefone: $fone \n Mensagem: $message"; // Vai fazer a leitura dos elementos dentro do conteúdo
$recipient = "contato@cupcode.com.br"; // Vai enviar para o remetente que se encontra dentro do $recipient
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n"; // Vai declarar para onde vai ser feito o envio
mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $mailheader) or die("Falha ao fazer o envio dos dados, tente novamente mais tarde!"); // Vai setar erro se tiver erro
echo "<script>window.location='index.php#contact-form';alert('$name, sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso! Estaremos retornando em breve');</script>";
?>
```

```html
<section id="contact-form" class="single-items text-left item-five parallaxie full-screen">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
               <form action="mail.php" method="POST" class="getin_form wow fadeInUp">
                  <div class="col-md-5 p-0">
                     <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 m-0 p-0">
                        <div class="form-group bottom45">
                           <input class="forma" name="Nome" type="name" placeholder="<?php echo $digitenome; ?>" required  alt="<?php echo $digitenome; ?>" title="<?php echo $digitenome; ?>" >
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 m-0 p-0">
                        <div class="form-group bottom45">
                           <input class="forma" name="E-mail" type="email" placeholder="<?php echo $digiteemail; ?>" required alt="<?php echo $digiteemail; ?>" title="<?php echo $digiteemail; ?>">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 m-0 p-0">
                        <div class="form-group bottom45">
                           <input class="forma" name="Telefone" type="fone" placeholder="<?php echo $digitefone; ?>" alt="<?php echo $digitefone; ?>" title="<?php echo $digitefone; ?>">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                     <div class="col-md-7 p-0">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                           <div class="form-group bottom45">
                              <textarea type="message" class="forma" name="Mensagem" placeholder="<?php echo $digitemensagem; ?>" alt="<?php echo $digitemensagem; ?>" title="<?php echo $digitemensagem; ?>"></textarea>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 text-right m-0 p-0">
                           <button id="form_submit" class="button defaulthole2" alt="<?php echo $btnenviar; ?>" title="<?php echo $btnenviar; ?>"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  <div class="alert-msg"> </div>
               </form>
            </div>
               <!-- aqui esta um espaço entre as colunas-->
               <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row col-md-4 mobile-p">
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                        <h2 class="bottom20 item-titles wow fadeInLeft ccdeep"><?php echo $contato; ?></h2>
                        <h3 class="bottom15"><a class="bottom20 item-titles text-center wow fadeInLeft ccdeep"  href="<?php echo $fone_link; ?>" alt="<?php echo $ligar; ?>" title="<?php echo $ligar; ?>"><?php echo $ccfone; ?></a></h3>
                        <h3><a class="bottom20 item-titles wow fadeInLeft ccdeep" href="mailto:<?php echo $contatoemail; ?>" alt="<?php echo $enviaremail; ?>" title="<?php echo $enviaremail; ?>"><?php echo $contatoemail; ?></a></h3>
                  </div>

                <a href="<?php echo $mensagemwhatsapp_link; ?>" target="_blank" class="button defaulthole mgr-10 mgb-10 top20"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $mensagemwhatsapp; ?></a>
                <a href="<?php echo $mensagemfacebook_link; ?>" target="_blank" class="button defaulthole mgr-10 top10"><i class="fab fa-facebook-messenger" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $mensagemfacebook; ?></a>
               </div>
            </div>
      </div>
   </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie um elemento html sem nenhum conteúdo dentro no local onde será exibida a mensagem.
`<div id="message"></div>`

aí neste javascript que vc está executando coloque
`document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "A mensagem que vc quer exibir"`

Comment: https://www.cupcode.com.br/index.php

Comment: Segue o link não deu certo no contato ele joga pra uma pagina HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: você substituiu o ```echo "<script>window.location='index.php#contact-form';alert('$name, sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso! Estaremos retornando em breve');</script>";``` por ```echo "<script>document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "A mensagem que vc quer exibir"</script>" ``` ?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/qb9hzk

Comment: Sim segue o link talvez eu tenha feito algo errado

Comment: ahhh, agora entendi o que você quer, não tinha visto que era um formulário que apontava para outra página. Você vai precisar de ajax para isso, tenta aprender com esse exemplo http://wbruno.com.br/ajax/enviar-formulario-para-php-sem-refresh-jquery-ajax/

Comment: Vou precisar estudar um pouco ajax agradeço pela tentativa da ajuda vou fechar aqui ok?